How to Access Parent Menus When Submenus Are Open in React with Material-UI?
I have implemented a dynamic menu component in React using Material-UI (@mui) that allows for nested menus and submenus. The behavior I'm trying to achieve is to have access to other menus (e.g., parent menus) while a submenu is open.
I have a setup where clicking on a menu item can either display a submenu or toggle a checkbox state. However, when a submenu is open, I want to be able to navigate back to the parent menu or access other top-level menus without closing the currently open submenu.
Here is a simplified version of my code:
import Menu from '@mui/material/Menu';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import Checkbox from '@mui/material/Checkbox';

const RecursiveMenu = ({ menuItems }) => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <IconButton
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        <MenuIcon />
      </IconButton>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        {Object.values(menuItems)
          .filter((menuItem) => menuItem.showing !== false)
          .map((menuItem) => (
            <RecursiveMenuItem key={menuItem.id} menuItem={menuItem} />
          ))}
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
};

const RecursiveMenuItem = ({ menuItem }) => {
  const [subMenuAnchorEl, setSubMenuAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const [showingState, setShowingState] = useState(menuItem.showing);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    if (menuItem.options) {
      setSubMenuAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
    } else {
      // Toggle between 0, 1, and 2 for checked, indeterminate, and unchecked
      setShowingState((prevState) => (prevState + 1) % 3);
    }
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setSubMenuAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <MenuItem style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between' }} onClick={handleClick}>
        <span>{menuItem.name}</span>
        {!menuItem.options && (
          <Checkbox
            checked={showingState === 0}
            indeterminate={showingState === 1}
            onChange={handleClick}
            inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'indeterminate-checkbox' }}
          />
        )}
      </MenuItem>
      {menuItem.options && (
        <Menu
          anchorEl={subMenuAnchorEl}
          open={Boolean(subMenuAnchorEl)}
          onClose={handleClose}
        >
          {Object.values(menuItem.options)
            .filter((subMenuItem) => subMenuItem.showing !== false)
            .map((subMenuItem) => (
              <RecursiveMenuItem key={subMenuItem.id} menuItem={subMenuItem} />
            ))}
        </Menu>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const menuItems = {
    A: { id: "A", name: "A", enabled: false, showing: 0 },
    B: { id: "B", name: "B", enabled: false, showing: 2 },
    C: {
      id: "c",
      name: "C",
      options: {
        C1: { id: "C1", name: "C1", enabled: false, showing: 1 },
        C2: {
          id: "C2", name: "C2", options:
          {
            C21: { id: "C21", name: "C2.1", enabled: false, showing: 0 },
            C22: { id: "C22", name: "C2.2", enabled: false, showing: 2 },
          }
        },
      },
    },
    Shaun: { id: "D", name: "D", enabled: false, showing: 2 },
  };

  return <RecursiveMenu menuItems={menuItems} />;
};

export default App; 

In this implementation:
Clicking on a menu item with menuItem.options displays a submenu.
Clicking on a menu item without options toggles a checkbox state.
Specifically, I'm looking to achieve the following:
Allow users to navigate to other menus while a submenu remains open.
Maintain the open state of the parent menu or previous menus when interacting with submenus.
What I've tried:
I've attempted to manage state using useState for the anchor element of submenus (subMenuAnchorEl) and the showing state of menu items (showingState).
Can someone provide guidance on how to achieve this behavior?
I'm open to suggestions or examples on how to better manage menu navigation and states in this context. Thank you!

